# Open, copy and paste cells from multiple workbook to one workbook to one sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have 15 excel files with two sheet. From each, cells A1:A48 should be copied from the first page to a new file in the sheet1, in order to the next column from the first cell. It only copies from 14 files. 15 the file opens but cells A1:A48 are not copied.

```
Sub OpenCopyAndPasteWorkbook()
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, Sheet1 As Worksheet, i As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbArray(15)

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   For i = 1 To 15
      wbArray(i) = ("d:\test\Book" & i)
      Workbooks.Open fileName:=wbArray(i)
      Workbooks(i).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A48").Copy _
Workbooks("Book20.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A48").Offset(0, i)
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Next i
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome! What is the purpose of wbArray(15) in this code? Also, Workbooks(i) in the copy statement doesn't necessarily match the last opened workbook, it's better to use ActiveWorkbook (after opening a new workbook it becomes active automatically - see [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open#example))

Comment: VBA array index start at 0 so I'm sure it should be `wbarray(i-1)`. There may be other cases that you have to do this type of offset.